# How to change the color of a text/item/css inside a *ngFor?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, colors

I have one item creater using an array, that creates a list of items using the *ngFor="let option.

I want to change the color of those items based on their values, but I cant seem to do it.

```js
tankItAwnserArray = ['Yes','Yes','Option','NO'];
```

```html
 <ion-item *ngFor="let option of tankItAwnserArray">
        <ion-item> Move Damage:  {{option}}</ion-item>
      </ion-item>
```

I want the "Yes" value to be Green, the "Option" to be orange and the "No" to be red.

I tried a lot of things but I cant see to make it work.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the conditional CSS class with *ngClass

---

**Component.HTML**

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let option of tankItAwnserArray">
    <ion-item>
        Move Damage:  
        <span [ngClass]="{'green-class': option === 'Yes', 'orange-class': option === 'Option', 'red-class': option === 'No' }">{{option}}</span>
    </ion-item>
</ion-item>
```

---

**Component.CSS**

```
.green-class { color: green; }
.orange-class { color: orange; }
.red-class { color: red; }
```

---

Comment: Its says "Selector matches unknown element green-class" on the css part

Comment: There should be a dot ( . ) before the CSS class names on the CSS file, I edited the answer.

Comment: I understand the code, but its not working. The text is still white/default

Answer (score 0):

```
    interface Colors {
    yes: string; 
    option: string;
    no: string;
    }

    const colors: Colors = {
    yes: '#336699',
    option: '#223366',
    no: '#223366'
    }

Push the colors from your JSON directly into the inline styles like...

<span [ngStyle]="{'color': colors[option.toLowercase()]}">{{option}}</span>
```